# how to capture the first and last crosshair coordinate data

Tags: javascript, html, event-listener, lightweight-charts

I have the following code that uses the native `addEventListener` on `mousedown` combined with a shift click.
Inside this function, I have a `lightweight-charts` native function called `subscribeCrosshairMove()` which allows me to get the x value on my chart as the crosshair moves.

```
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){
    if(e.shiftKey == 1){
        console.log('mouse and shift was pressed');
        async function crossHairEvent(param){
            try{
                console.log(param.time);
            }
            catch{}
        };
        chart.subscribeCrosshairMove(crossHairEvent);
    }
})
```

I tried to assign an undefined variable `initialX` like below to assign the very first X value from the crosshair:

```
let initialX;
if(initialX == undefined){
initialX = param.time;
console.log(initialX);
}
else{console.log('else')}
```

adding this code to the try block, I expected the very first X value from the crosshair to be assigned to `initialX` variable because after the first assignment, it is no longer `undefined`. But it did not work. the `else` statement never got executed.

`console.log(initialX);` keeps changing values as I move the cursor.

I want to callback the first and the last values from the crosshair movement. How can I do this?

edit1: so I figured out how to obtain the last recorded value of X from the crosshair. I just push the data into an array and unsubscribe from crosshairmove. Then the function is finished and I fetch the last element from the array.

But fetching the first data from the data gives me `undefined` because `subscribeCrosshairMove()` hasnt officially concluded yet while the crosshair is still moving. Looking for suggestions or hints here. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

- The reason why the [ ***else*** ] block never runs is because of you are putting the variable  `let initialX` inside the try block. This means that every time the mouse is moving `let initialX` will get undefined.
- As a solution for your problem I think that you need to put the value of `param.time` somewhere outside the eventListener function.
  As I understood that you need to register tow different values fromX and toX, that means you need to know the distance between this tow X coordinates.

```js
let coordinates = {
    shiftKey: false,
    fromX: null,
    toX : null
}

let fromX = null;
let toX = null;

// Register the shiftKey pressing  & releasing.
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function( e ){ 
    
    if( e.shiftKey && !coordinates.shiftKey ) {
        coordinates.shiftKey = true;
    }

    if( !e.shiftKey && coordinates.shiftKey ) {
        coordinates.shiftKey = false;
    }

})

async function crossHairEvent(param){
    try{
        // Register the fromX
        if( coordinates.shiftKey && !coordinates.fromX ) {
            coordinates.fromX = param.time;
        }
        // Register the toX
        if( !coordinates.shiftKey && !coordinates.toX ) {
            coordinates.fromX = param.time;
        }

        // Save the values in a deifferent variables.
        if( coordinates.fromX &&  coordinates.toX ) {
            fromX = coordinates.fromX;
            toX = coordinates.toX ;

            // Set them to null to make it possible to register every time you release the shiftKey.
            coordinates.fromX = null;
            coordinates.toX = null;

        }
    }
    catch{}
};

chart.subscribeCrosshairMove(crossHairEvent);
```

This seems to be a longer solution but it is just an example for demonstrating the way you could save values from an eventListener.